# SQL pivot-like records arrangement

Tags: sql, pivot, axis, direction

I have following table which carries records.

```
ID header      value
1  firstname   James
1  lastname    Tulan
2  firstname   Berty
2  lastname    O-Nelly
3  firstname   Ana
3  lastname    Santos
```

I need to display the records as follows

```
id firstname    Lastname
1  James        Tulan
2  Berty        O-Nelly
3  Ana          Santos
```

I tried to use SQL PIVOT function. It didn't work properly. Anyone encountered the same?

Comment: "It didn't work properly" - sigh.......

Comment: Should the ids in the sample data really be 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3 ?

Comment: How about showing the query that you used that didn't work properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the ids in the first table do identify the pairs, you can just do aggregation:

```
select id,
       max(case when header = 'firstname' then value end) as firstname,
       max(case when header = 'lastname' then value end) as lastname
from t
group by id;
```